# Gradient of implicit symbolic expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient, symbolic-math

The situation I have is as follows:
I have a symbolic expression like:

```
syms X Y Z K
Ra=51.7;
P=[0 0 200];

Sa=sym('Ra^2==(Z-P(3))^2+(Y-P(2))^2')
```

Where `Y` and `Z` are defined as symbolic. `Ra` and `P` are vectors.
I need to get the gradient of `Sa` but I get an error:

```
G=gradient(Sa,[Y Z]);

Error using symengine (line 59)
The first argument must be of type 'Type::Arithmetical'.

Error in sym/gradient (line 39)
    res = mupadmex('symobj::gradient',fsym.s,x.s);
```

But if I write the same expression as:

```
Sa(Y,Z)=((Z-P(3))^2+(Y-P(2))^2-Ra^2);
```

I get the expected result

```
G=gradient(Sa,[Y Z])

G(X, Y, Z) =

       2*Y
 2*Z - 400
```

Does anyone knows why this is so and if there's any way of using the implicit expression as this is a particular case but in general I have different implicit expressions and my code should be able to deal with them.

I've read the documentation on `gradient` and some sites, but if I found the answer I didn't notice.

I believe I could use the second form but still, I am curious about this subject.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I assume its because in the second one, you explicitly define `Sa` being dependant on `Y` and `Z` while in the first one its an equation, not a function that you can derive

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thanks for your comment. I hadn't noticed before but in relation to your comment I checked and the first definition of `Sa` its class `sym` wehreas the second definition's class is `symfun`. Maybe that has something to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one Sa is the entire equation, including the `==`, while in the second one its a symbolic function depending on 2 variables.

Ultimately the way MATLAB seems to be handle this is that the first one is not derivable (also its dependent in another 2 `sym` variables, that doesn't know if they are related or not to the derived ones), while the second one gets identified as a function (symbolic) and can get derived.